# Using not statement on false boolean

Tags: java, boolean

I'm always assumed that if a statement was declared false, such as `boolean valid = false`, then writing `!valid` would in turn reverse `valid` to be true. Yet, was this an entirely wrong misconception? For instance, in the code below;

```
for (int check=3; check <= primeLimit; check += 2) {
    boolean divisorFound=false;
    for (int div=3; div<=Math.sqrt(check) && !divisorFound; div += 2) {
        if (check%div==0)
            divisorFound=true;
    }
```

Is the second for loop searching for `divisorFound` to be true of false?
Because if it was implying that the divisor is false, wouldn't it just say :

```
div<=Math.sqrt(check) && divisorFound;
```

Comment: Here the for loop searches for !divisorFound to be false in order to stop so it searches for divisorFound to be true to stop. 

An advice; the for loop is dedicated to something to be repeated exactly n times. To use the Boolean variables, while loop is more useful.

Comment: @pbabcdefp, Thank-you, that's just what I wanted to clarify. I was embarrassed to ask this question because it seems so trivial, but double negation always has confused me. And I thought that this code was implying that in order for the loop to run, divisorFound had to be false, but it was simply saying that it would run until there was a condition that made divisorFound true.

Comment: That's ok. Nothing wrong with simple questions. I make really basic mistakes all the time - I had to delete my comment as it contained a really embarrassing error. I would advise you to use `System.out.println(...)` a lot to keep track of variables and see what's going on. It's a very effective way of learning.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm assuming you didn't write this code and are trying to understand what it's purpose is. The inner loop should continue until a divisor is found. So it repeatedly checks to see if `!divisorFound` evaluates to `true`. In other words, "has a divisor *not* been found yet?".

Once a divisor is found, `divisorFound` is set to `true` and the expression `!divisorFound` evaluates to `false`, so the loop will stop.

If the condition check that you suggested was used:

```
div<=Math.sqrt(check) && divisorFound
```

The loop body would never be reached. `divisorFound` is `false` to start with so the continue condition would immediately fail and the loop would terminate.

Answer (score 1):

The second loop is saying to continue looping when `div` is less than `Math.sqrt(check)` and no divisor has been found. When `divisorFound` has been set to true, then the inner loop will fail its condition.

I think you must have misread the code as this is a pretty straight forward boolean condition.